# Attach a file to a PDF using Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, jspdf

I am struggling with attaching files to a PDF that I am generating at runtime.

I'm using Javascript. I originally created the PDF using jsPDF from a HTML View but I then realised, I also needed to attach files to the PDF.

The problem I have now is that I can't seem to find a library that can help me attach those files

Comment: The LEADTOOLS JavaScript Toolkit (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor) provides the ability to manage PDF [Document Attachments](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/javascript/to/document-attachments.html), allowing for the extraction and addition of other documents and files as attachments.

Comment: Are you running jsPDF client side in the browser? Or server side on your backend?